# Change order of properties in a Properties View

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have an implementation of "Properties View" of Eclipse and I implemented using `IPropertySource` interface.

I override the method `getPropertyDescriptors` and return the descriptors in the order that I want.

```
@Override
public IPropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
    return descriptors;
}
```

But the properties in the view are sorted in alphabetic order. I need to show the descriptors in the order returned by `getPropertyDescriptor`. Is it possible? Or can I implementing my own sorter?

Comment: Are you providing properties for a View or Editor? You can use your own property sheet page if you are.

Comment: I have a editor and I set the plugin.xml to use the adapter IPropertySource. I implemented IAdapterFactory and override the methods getAdapter(...) and getAdapterList().

Comment: The adapter is IPropertySource.class. It is NOT IPropertySheetPage.class... May I use property sheet page even so? How?

Answer (score 1):

Try returning a custom property sheet page from the `getAdapter` of your editor:

```
@Override
public Object getAdapter(Class key) {
    if (key.equals(IPropertySheetPage.class)) {
        return custom property sheet page;
    }
    return super.getAdapter(key);
}
```

The custom page can extend the standard `PropertySheetPage` but call the `setSorter` method in the constructor:

```
public class CustomPropertySheetPage extends PropertySheetPage
{
  public CustomPropertySheetPage()
  {
    setSorter(custom PropertySheetSorter);
  }
}
```

The sorter should extended `PropertySheetSorter`.

Comment: I'm using this extension in plugin.xml, if I change the type type IPropertySource to IPropertySheetPage, the getAdapter never execute.

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.adapters">
      <factory
            adaptableType="MyComponent"
            class="MyComponentAdapterFactory">
         <adapter
               type="org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.IPropertySource">
         </adapter>
      </factory>
   </extension>

Comment: You don't change your existing adapter factory. The above code is extra code that you need to set up a custom property page.

Comment: I tried to change this extension because the key in getAdapter never is IPropertySheetPage.class. Its only IPropertySource.class.

Comment: If the properties view is open and the editor becomes active the editor getAdapter does get a request for the IPropertySheetPage

Comment: In my case the properties view only update when I click in ouline. That is, the getAdapter only executes if I select a item in outline and the only class is IPropertySource. Is that a problem?

Comment: My class AdapterFactory implements IAdapterFactory and the method adapter is  Object getAdapter(Object adaptableObject, Class adapterClass)

Comment: That is fine for the AdapterFactory. The code I gave you is the getAdapter for the actual editor class.